# ¿Cómo poner un OnClick en un RecycleView?

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, onclick, onclicklistener

llevo rato intentado integrar un onClick de manera correcta en un Recycleview y no doy con las solución correcta, he visto otros ejemplos de hace años que no he logrado hacer funcionar ( deduzco que porque ya no se hará así )

**Este es mi adaptador:**

```
private class AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritas.AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemfav,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imprimit(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nombres.length;
    }


    private class AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView tv1;
            ImageView iv1;
            public AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                iv1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                tv1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            }

        public void imprimit(int position) {
                iv1.setImageResource(fotos[position]);
                tv1.setText(nombres[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

en un intento mío he intentado implementar a la clase un *View.OnClickListener* y he creado el metodo onCLick dentro.
Pero cuando intento hacer un *setOnclickListener()* en el **OncreateViewHolder** tengo errores que no logro hacer funcionar.

¿Me podríais orientar con una solución rápida que lance un *toast* simple al hacer click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi lo que me ha servido es ponerlo en el metodo onViewHolder

```html
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imprimit(position);
        // holder.componente().setOnclikcListener(new OnClickListener())
    }
```

Tambien recuerda que el "componente" debe estar referenciado en el Holder tal que

```html
            public AdaptadorPeliculasFavoritasHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                iv1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                tv1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                //componente=itemView.findById(R.id.componenteClick);

            }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! problema solucionado :D